# Unable to populate JSON object from SocketIO into front end React table

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I have successfully made a connection to the node back end server through socketIO. The data is coming through to the front end and can currently display in the console as a JSON array of objects. I am now unable to populate the data into a table. Any suggestions welcome.

```
import React from 'react';
import socketIO from 'socket.io-client';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';

class Updates extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataSocket: {},
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var socket = socketIO('http://127.0.0.1:5007');
        socket.on('chat message', function (dataSocket) {
            console.log(dataSocket)
            console.log(typeof dataSocket) // displays "object"
        });
    }


    render() {
        const { dataSocket } = this.state;
        const data = dataSocket.cc || [];
        return (
            <Container>
            <h1>Snowdon Updates</h1>
                <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Device</th> 
                            <th>DeviceName</th>
                            <th>Input</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {data.map(dataTable => (
                        <tr>
                        <td>{dataTable.ID}</td> <td>{dataTable.Device}</td> 
                        <td>{dataTable.DeviceName}</td> <td>{dataTable.Input}</td>
                        </tr>
                        ))}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </Container>
         );
     } 
}

export default Updates;
```

**update**
I have just added this and still dosent work and im unable to console log the incoming data:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var socket = socketIO('http://127.0.0.1:5007');
    socket.on("message", dataSocket => this.setState({ data: dataSocket }));
}
```

**update** Back end node Js code

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
var port = process.env.PORT || 5007;

amqp.connect('amqp://dell-docker', function(error0, connection) {
    if (error0) {
        throw error0;
    }
connection.createChannel(function(error1, channel) {
    if (error1) {
        throw error1;
    }
    var exchange = 'states';
    channel.assertExchange(exchange, 'fanout', {
        durable: false
    });
    channel.assertQueue('', {
        exclusive: true 
    }, 
    function(error2, q) {
        if (error2) {
            throw error2;
        }
        console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", q.queue);
        channel.bindQueue(q.queue, exchange, '');

        channel.consume(q.queue, function(msg) {
            if(msg.content) {
                var dataParse = JSON.parse(msg.content.toString()) 
                console.log(dataParse);
                io.emit('chat message', dataParse);  
            }
            }, 
        {
            noAck: true
        });
    });
})
});



http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

Comment: I dont see you updating state, ie setState(...)

Comment: Just updated my code. Still not working socket.on("message", dataSocket => this.setState({ data: dataSocket }));

Comment: Your state property name is `dataSocket` not `data`, eg `setState({ dataSocket: dataSocket })`

Comment: if `console.log(dataSocket)` doesnt show anything when inside your message callback then you arent sending the data correctly

Comment: Edited, still not working `socket.on("message", data => this.setState({ dataSocket: data }));`

Comment: What exactly does `console.log(dataSocket)` show, and provide the backend code that sends your data

Comment: Without updating state and just logging it shows `Object { ID: 2, Device: 1, DeviceName: "Device 1", Input: 2, InputName: "Input 2", InputState: 0, OnPhrase: "On", OffPhrase: "Off", When: "2019-11-08T11:10:50.895852+00:00" }` getting the same message with different data every second

Comment: You try to use `dataSocket.cc` in your render but you dont have a `cc` property in that data. So it looks like you arent sending that data in the format you wrote the frontend to expect

Comment: TypeError: data.map is not a function if i remove the .cc

Comment: Yea because you sent an object not an array. the problem is the server code isnt sending the data in the correct format

Comment: I have tried sending as an array, object and string. Still the same outcome if i update the state as suggested. nothing appears in table

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update the state with your data ?

```
this.setState({ data: dataSocket });
```

Comment: Just updated my code. Still not working `socket.on("message", dataSocket => this.setState({ data: dataSocket }));`

Comment: Can you add you dataSocket output when logging ? It has to be an array

Comment: prior to setting the state it appears in the console as `Object { ID: 2, Device: 1, DeviceName: "Device 1", Input: 2, InputName: "Input 2", InputState: 0, OnPhrase: "On", OffPhrase: "Off", When: "2019-11-08T11:10:50.895852+00:00" } ` however i converted it to array from the backend but still could not get any output on the table

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
JSON.parse(dataSocket);
```

Comment: You should add an explanation of why this solves OP's problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your answer may solve this question, it would be helpful if you would include an explanation of how and why it solves it. Also, have in mind that you will help any future visitor to this question if you provide quality answer, which in turn may result with up-votes . I would encourage you to edit your answer and add explanations of how and why it solves this question.